# CentOS Grub won't boot to windows 10

Tags: centos, windows, dual-boot

Hi I just installed CentOS 7 beside Windows 10 x64 but grub won't find win disks and add it to boot menu :( Thhing is that even installing os-prober, ntfs3g and ntfsprogs it still doesn't work.

I attach files with lsblk and blkid logs.

Regards, Horacy.

Logs: http://pastebin.com/eHWQWtuz

Answer (score 0):

You have to install CentOS in 100% *UEFI* mode. Disable ALL *Legacy* compatability modes like e.g. *CSM* in the *BIOS*.
Reinstall CentOS in *UEFI* mode selected in *BIOS* or boot selector. Then it has to work.